# Posting from a form in a table

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

I am trying to retrieve records from db and put them into a table. I want to have an update button which can do some processing. Here is the code. It outputs properly. However the update button (image) doesn't work. Please help

```
<?php
echo "</br>";
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Customer Number</th>
<th>Order Items</th>
<th>Transaction Time</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>";
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("kaka", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status = 'NRDY'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {
  echo "<div class=\"update\"><form method='post' action=\"test.php\">\n";  
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='".$row1['order_id']."'>" .$row1['order_id']. "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='cust_num' value='".$row1['cust_num']."'>" .$row1['cust_num']. "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='items' value='".$row1['items']."'>" .$row1['items']. "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='order_time' value='".$row1['order_time']."'>" .$row1['order_time']. "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='".$row1['amount']."'>" .$row1['amount']. "</td>";
  //echo "<td>" . $row1['order_id'] . "</td>";
  //echo "<td>" . $row1['cust_num'] . "</td>";
  //echo "<td>" . $row1['items'] . "</td>";
  //echo "<td>" . $row1['order_time'] . "</td>";
  //echo "<td>" . $row1['amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=\"image\" src=\"images/update.png\" alt=\"Update Row\" class=\"update\" title=\"Update Row\">\n" . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form></div>";  
  }

 echo "</table>";
?>
```

Here is test.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['order_id'];
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code. The big red box on the [manual page](http://php.net/mysql_query) is there for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org). You aren't allowed to wrap divs or forms around table rows. Some browsers recover from this error by moving the div/form so it is outside the table (leaving the content behind). Your inputs are therefore not inside a form so shouldn't be expected to do anything.

Comment: is there a simpler way of what i am trying to do?